# What does the int*. syntax do?

Tags: c++

I am a newbie in C++ and this question will be probably so easy to answer for you. I can't find the actual meaning of this kind of syntax. So I have:

```
struct Vec {        
double x, y, z; 
Vec(double x_=0, double y_=0, double z_=0){ x=x_; y=y_; z=z_; } 
};

int w = 1024, h = 768;
Vec cx = Vec(w*.5135/h);
```

What is happening in the last row? I am creating a new struct of type Vec and, what else ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a multiplication operator.

Comment: Same as `w * 0.5135 / h`

Comment: An other reason to not use [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

Comment: Also, I would put the 0 in so it is less confusing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a short way of writing floating point numbers. You can do that both ways(it has to be either a double of float of course). A decimal number is divided in 3 parts (excluding the sign that is):

```
123 . 456
 |  |  \_fractional part
 |  |
 |  \_decimal point
 |
integer part
```

- When the integer part is equal to 0 but the fractional part is not:

  ```
  double x = .123; // the same as writing 0.123
  ```
- When the fractional part is equal to 0 but the integer part is not:

  ```
  double x = 123.; // the same as writing 123.0
  ```

The `*` is just your standard multiplication here. You are just multiplying an integer number `w` with a decimal number `.5135` that has its integer part equal to 0.

Answer (score 2):

it is equivalent to:

```
Vec cx = Vec(w*0.5135/h);
```

Comment: Ok thanks.. I am sorry I didn't know it meant to be 0.5135. And about the Vec cx = Vec(...) ? is it a way to initialize a struct? I always used to do: Vec cx = {x,y,z}; why there is the second "Vec" after the equal and why only 1 value is used when the struct wants 3 values?

Comment: This called the class constructor and most probably you are setting the size of the vector here.

Comment: but the struct constructor is the one you can see above and it accepts 3 values..

Comment: maybe its the default constructor. i have no idea

Comment: The three-argument constructor of `Vec` has default values of 0 (indicated by `=0` after each argument name), which means you can call it with none, one, two, or three parameters. Any omitted parameters will be initialised to zero.

Comment: The constructor has default values of zero. If you only pass one value to the constructor the others will be initialized to zero. The vector in the example is initialized to Vec(w*0.5135/h, 0, 0)

Answer (score 1):

In the last row you're assignming `cx` with a newly constructor instance of type `Vec` by calling it's constructor `Vec(double x_=0, double y_=0, double z_=0)`.

```
Vec cx = Vec(w*.5135/h);
```

Is the same as:

```
Vec cx = Vec(w*0.5135/h, 0, 0);
```

Because of the default values for the parameters defined by the constructor.

An floating point number doesn't have to start with a `0` in C++.

```
assert(0.5135 == .5135); // True
```

So `w*.5135` is just a multiplication of integer `w` and double `0.5135`.